# git push: failed to push

Tags: git, git-push

```
git push origin testing
```

> To git@git.site.com:cgp/project.git
>
> ! [rejected]        testing -> testing (non-fast-forward)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.site.com:cgp/project.git'
>
> hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
>
> hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
>
> hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Как таки запушить?
Из master'а влиты последния изменения в мою ветку разработки. Создал свою для разработки, закачиваю в удаленную ветку для тестирования.

Comment: У меня часто эта ошибка бывает, притом никто кроме меня не правит репозитории, и через веб-интерфейс правок не делаю. Решаю проблему командой `git push -f`. Перед этим на всякий случай делаю бэкап папки `.git` в локальном репозитории, поскольку история коммитов может удалиться (но не должна, однажды было только). `git pull`, как тут все советуют, перепишет файлы на Вашем локальном репозитории, файлами с удалённого, имеющими те же имена и пути, поэтому я не использую `git pull` при этой ошибке. Спасибо.

Comment: git pull не перетирает файлы:) А Вы случайно не пользуетесь какими-нибудь source tree/tortolize и подобными поделками с гуем?

Comment: @СашаЧерных Вы неправы. Во-первых, `git push -f` лучше бездумно не делать. Во-вторых, при любом `git push` локальная история не может удалиться, могут только переписаться локальные копии remote веток, но ведь вы и хотите это сделать. В-третьих, `git pull` не "переписывает файлы", он добавляет новую историю коммитов, не удаляя существующую.

Comment: @KoVadim, пользуюсь плагинами для Sublime Text. Для большинства действий использую [**пакет Git**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeGit) Чтобы быстро сделать push — [**easygit**](https://github.com/silentninja/easygit). Спасибо.

Comment: вот вот. Многие подобные утилиты делают в тихую синхронизацию - то есть делают pull. И это может быть причиной. Но лучше конечно смотреть в лог и выяснять.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В данный момент Вы пытаетесь запушить в ветку над которой работаете не только Вы. Вы столкнулись с этой проблемой, так как на сервере появились изменения, которых нет у Вас.

Ваша последовательность действий должна быть следующей:

1. Забрать изменения из удалённой ветки:

   ```
   git pull
   ```
2. Далее, необходимо разрешить конфликты (смёржить изменения), если таковые присутствуют. Для этого надо воспользоваться следующей командой:

   ```
   git mergetool
   ```
3. Если конфликты были и вы их разрешили, то Вам нужно будет создать новый коммит, который будет содержать исправление конфликтов:

   ```
   git commit
   ```
4. Вы можете выполнить отправку своих изменений:

   ```
   git push
   ```

**Если у Вас нет конфликтов, то шаг 2 и 3 можно пропустить.**

Comment: вообще то git pull по умолчанию делает git fetch + git merge. так что либо первый шаг поправить, либо в втором написать, что он выполняется автоматически.

Comment: @KoVadim, согласен, моя оплошность. Надо `mergetool` :)

Comment: А как работает команда `git mergetool`?

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, для работы с Git-ом, для большего удобства, Вам необходимо настроить какую-нибудь утилиту для слияния изменений. Например, kdiff3, beyond compare или что-то из этой серии. Это утилиты, которые показывают Вам визуально конфликты, они покажут два файла рядом и их разницу.

Comment: Правильнее всё-таки *rebase*.

Comment: всё зависит от того, как Вы договорились с коллегами. `rebase` не всегда лучшее решение)

Answer (score 6):

Скорее всего на удаленной ветке есть новые коммиты которые у тебя отсутствуют. Это можно решит вот так

```
git pull origin ветка
```

Если не поможет (значит есть конфликты) то можно вот так

```
git pull --rebase origin ветка
```

Но данная проблема могла появиться если ты что небудь перезаписал в истории Git например закоммител через git --amend либо сделал rebase или cherry-pick...
В таких случаях необходим "насильственно" протолкнуть изменения репозтирий. Это можно выполнить вот таким образом

```
git push -f origin ветка
```

Answer (score 4):

Кто-то успел добавить изменения раньше вас. Вам надо выкачать эти изменения, интегрировать их в свою ветку и потом залить еще раз.

```
git pull origin testing

разрешение конфликтов (commit)

git push origin testing
```

Comment: А не пропадут ли в таком случае изменения, сделанные автором вопроса в локальном репозитории? Спасибо.

Comment: Но ведь в ветке testing можно быть много лишнего, что еще только тестируется.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Если вы выполните 2ой пункт, то ничего не пропадет.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov вы можете указать, что именно вы хотите залить поместить в ветку используя `git add`. Только указанные файлы и директории будет добавлены в ветку.

Comment: В данном случае я про команду `git pull` - сделав ее, не залью ли я к себе в в dev-ветку то, что тестируется (множество разного функционала)?

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, команда `git pull` же перепишет файлы, имеющие такие же названия, что и в локальном репозитории. Возможно, автору вопроса этого не хотелось бы.

Comment: @СашаЧерных не перепишет, будет показана ошибка, что файлы уже есть и что их надо либо добавить, либо удалить.

Comment: Mikhail Vaysman, я изменил файл в веб-интерфейсе → сделал git pull → соответствующий файл в локальном репозитории стал иметь такое же содержание, как и на удалённом. Никаких ошибок не появляется при этом. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных локальный файл содержал новый код? или он был точной копией файла с веба до изменения?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы не знаете что добавлено в ветку testing (Возможен вариант что ветка может сломаться другим кодом). Отколите  новую ветку   от testing git checkout -b testing2. Потому в ветке testing2 сделайте git pull origin testing. Далее останется самое сложное - разрешить конфликты  и проверить работоспособность Вашего кода. Закомитте Ваш код (git commit -a -m "SOME COMMENT").  Если всё работает перейдите на ветку testing (git checkout testing) и смержите ветку с testing2 (git merge testing2). Так как HEAD ветки testing2 выше testing конфликтов не будет.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, такой ответ еще возможен в случае, если конкретная ветка защищена от push'а. В этом случае заливка в нее возможна лишь через merge requests.